# Why is HttpURLConnection not resending PUT content when it retries connection after 401 response?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I've got a bit of a weird issue with HttpURLConnection on Android (API level 7). I'm using basic authentication, set up using the default Authenticator like so:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

I'm making a standard request as follows:

```
public InputStream put(String type, String name, String xml){

    try{
        String urlString = this.getURLString(type,name);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(xml);
        out.close();
        urlConnection.getInputStream();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        return null;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        return urlConnection.getErrorStream();
    }
}
```

A packet trace shows that the content is being sent with the HTTP request. I then receive a 401 Unauthorized from the server, and resend the response. This time the credentials are sent as I'd expect, but the content is no longer being sent. It's now a blank PUT request with a Content-Length of 0.

Has anyone seen this before, and how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have eventually solved this by not using the Authenticator and instead adding the Basic Authorization header manually to the HttpURLConnection.